# Python Telnet simple test ends up with a connection refused

Tags: python, telnet

I am having the same kind of errors since more than 6 hours now, I don't get my simple telnet python code to work, even if it's ridiculously easy and simple.

I am using Python 2.7.10
Here it is.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import telnetlib

HOST = "192.168.1.10"
tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)

tn.write("Message for the receiver \n")

tn.read_until("\n")
```

I tried a lot of different codes, and all return those errors :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runsimple.py", line 8, in <module>
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/telnetlib.py", line 211, in __init__
    self.open(host, port, timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/telnetlib.py", line 227, in open
    self.sock = socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 575, in create_connection
    raise err
socket.error: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

The IP of what I am trying to connect to is correct, and is open, as it is a tiny simple server. The purpose is to send some strings to this server for him to read them.

I tested nearly all solutions found on StackOverflow now and all result in such errors.

If somebody encountered the same problem / know what is the cause, it would help me so much..

Thanks a lot.. I don't have more to help, since it's a very simple code...

Comment: Can you telnet on the command line with the port you are using?

Comment: Are you sure that your firewall rules allow for incoming connection on port 23?

Comment: And does this work if you use the standard telnet command in your shell?

Comment: I opened my server on the port "5555", and I tried to give the `HOST` the port with the ip and the timeout, like this : `HOST = "192.168.1.10", "5555","5"` and I end up with another error : `TypeError: a float is required`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server is using a non-standard port number. Try specifying the port number in the client:

```
tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST, 5555)
```

Note: the port number is specified as an actual number, not a string. Do not please `"`-quotes around the number.

Comment: You fixed it ! I've seen 2 times the `"` around the port when defining it, and I stupidly copied that ... Thanks a lot !